# Как вытащить картинки сайта с сохранением структуры каталогов

Tags: php, javascript

На сайте (интернет-магазин) есть папка /sources (внутри глубокая структура), в которой лежат все изображения товаров. Со временем папка очень увеличилась (более 200гб), хочется почистить ее от неиспользуемого мусора.

Есть ли возможность вытащить из нее только используемые картинки с сохранением структуры каталогов, чтобы потом эту структуру скопировать в папку с новым именем, поменять пути в шаблоне, а эту папку (sources) полностью удалить ?

Comment: А по какому признаку Вы намерены отсеивать эти самые _только используемые картинки_? Где и в каком виде у Вас имеется признак "используемости"?

Comment: составить отдельный список url картинок сайта, например, взять из отчета той же xenu

Comment: Ну насчет пхп не уверен, а вот насчет [C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320(v=vs.85).aspx) - да. Там, по времени последнего доступа к файлу можно понять, когда же он использовался - нужен ли он нынче. Возможно костыльно, зато просто

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам не впадлу этим заниматься. В зависимости от CMS. Например в MODX я бы слил всю бд в массивы, преобразовал в строки и пробежался бы по всему содержимому регуляркой аля  /sources/* с выбором всех совпадений в массив. Надо не забыть, что css файлы не хранятся в базе, соответственно по ним надо пробежать отдельно. Так можно получить полный список используемых изображений. Всё это надо будет хотя бы поверхностно просматривать, дабы не было лажи.
Дальше на Ваше усмотрение. Можно на php написать скрипт, который пробежится по всем файлам и удалит те, которых нет в массиве с используемыми. Можно вручную почистить, имея упорядоченный список на руках, наверняка можно будет удалять файлы почти целыми папками. Другой вопрос, что с openCart такой фокус не пройдёт. Надо разобраться как выдрать список всех используемых файлов.
В сумме этот процесс займёт довольно значительное время и обязательно потребуется резервная копия всех файлов.
По скольку более конкретной информации по вопросу нет, предложить что-то более разумное я не могу.

Comment: чем плох список проверки xenu?

Comment: никогда не пользовался им. Понятия не имею как он работает. А собственно в чём проблема, если Вы можете сформировать список актуальных файлов, остальное то уже дело техники. Выкачать папку и скриптом убить всё лишнее, зачем Вам именно выдёргивать актуальные в новую структуру?

Comment: опять же, если привести список актуальных файлов в порядок, то можно залить его в массив и скриптом по нему пробежаться - вытащить из структуры соответствующие файлы и так же уложить в новой папке. Что именно вызывает у Вас затруднения?